# Convert Infix to Prefix Notation

Tags: c++, stack, queue, polish-notation

I have a task: make a program (C++), which converts "infix" notation to "prefix" and uses own "stack and queue" realizations.

But I get: `"Critical error detected c0000374"` and `"Free Heap block modified at ... after it was freed"` at last string of `void main() { /*...*/ system("pause"); }` or at last string of `void toPrefix();`

Can somebody help me and point out my mistake(s), please?

*Source.cpp:*

```
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "string"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Queue.h"

void toPrefix(const std::string& first)
{
    int length = first.length();
    char test = NULL, operand = NULL;
    char *ptr = &test, *op_ptr = &operand;
    Queue<char> List;
    std::string Output;
    Stack<char> OpStack;
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) List.push(first[i]); //
    while (List.getsize() != 0)
    {
        List.pop(ptr);
        if (test >= 48 && test <= 57) //is it number?
        {
            Output.insert(Output.begin(), test);
        }
        if (test == '*' || test == '/' || test == '-' || test == '+')
        {
            OpStack.push(test);
        }
        if (test == ')')
        {
            OpStack.push(test);
        }
        if (test == '(')
        {
            OpStack.pop(op_ptr);
            while (operand != ')')
            {
                Output.insert(Output.begin(), operand);
                OpStack.pop(op_ptr);
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    const std::string& first = "9-(2+2)";
    toPrefix(first);
    system("pause");
}
```

*Queue.h:*

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
private:
    struct queue_element
    {
        T value;
        queue_element *next;
    };

    queue_element *first;
    queue_element *last;
    int size;

public:
    Queue()
    {
        first = new(queue_element);
        last = first;
        first->value = -1;
        first->next = 0;
        size = 0;
    }
    Queue(T x)
    {
        first = new(queue_element);
        last = first;
        first->value = x;
        first->next = 0;
        size = 1;
    }

    int getsize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    void push(T value)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            size++;
            last = first;
            first->value = value;
            first->next = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            size++;
            queue_element *temp = new(queue_element);
            temp->next = 0;
            temp->value = value;
            last->next = temp;
            last = temp;
        }
    }

    void pop(T* ret)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Queue is empty!" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        queue_element *temp = first;
        *ret = first->value;
        first = first->next;
        size--;
    }

    void peek(T *ret)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Queue is empty!" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        *ret = first->value;
    }
};
```

*Stack.h*

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
private:
    struct stack_element
    {
        T value;
        stack_element *next;
    };
    stack_element *first;
    stack_element *last;
    int size;

public:
    Stack()
    {
        last = new(stack_element);
        first = last;
        last->value = -1;
        last->next = first;
        size = 0;
    }
    Stack(T x)
    {
        last = new(stack_element);
        first = last;
        last->value = x;
        last->next = 0;
        size = 1;
    }

    int getsize()
    {
        return size;
    }

    void push(T value)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            size++;
            last->value = value;
            last->next = first;
        }
        else
        {
            size++;
            stack_element *temp = new(stack_element);
            temp->next = last;
            temp->value = value;
            last = temp;
        }
    }

    void pop(T* ret)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Stack is empty!" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        stack_element *temp = last;
        *ret = last->value;
        last = last->next;
        delete temp;
        size--;
    }

    void peek(T *ret)
    {
        if (size == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Stack is empty!" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        *ret = first->value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your mistake is that you don't use a debugger.

Comment: Most likely, you're right. But only, that it tells: "Critical error detected c0000374" or "Free Heap block modified at ... after it was freed". I guess it's about the indexes or misuse "delete", because when I commented "delete temp" at Stack.h, everything works. But at that moment I don't know what exactly wrong. I will look for more information.

Comment: A debugger can do more than just tell you an error message. With a debugger you can step line-by-line through your code, and examine all variables and their contents at any point. One very obvious error is that your code that handles '(' and ')' is backwards, so the first thing it will do is attempt to pop an empty stack. Hillarity ensues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I think that the problem is in you `Stack` class.

The string that you pass to `toPrefix()` is `"9-(2+2)"`

So the operation in you `Stack<char> OpStack`, defined in `toPrefix()`, are (if I understand well)

1. construction with default (no arguments) constructor
2. `push()` in correspondence of `-`
3. `pop()` in correspondence od `(`
4. `push()` in correspondence of `+`
5. `push()` in correspondence of `)`

Well, let's see what's is happening in it

**1) after the construction with default constructor**

we have

1a) `size == 0`

1b) `first`, `last`, `first->next` and `last->next` that are pointing to the same allocated memory area

1c) `first->value == last->value == (char)-1`

**2) after the first call to `push()` (with `-`)**

we have

2a) `size == 1`

2b) `first`, `last`, `first->next` and `last->next` that are pointing to the same allocated memory area

2c) `first->value == last->value == '-'`

**3) after the first call to `pop()`**

we have

3a) `size == 0`

3b) **`first`, `last`, `first->next` and `last->next` that are pointing to the same DELETED memory area**

3c) `first->value == last->value == '-'`

**4) calling for the second time `push()` (with `+`)**

4a) `size` is incremented

4b) **is written (`last->value = value;`) in a DELETED area**

4c) **is written again (`last->next = first;`) in a DELETED area**

I suppose that this can explain your problem.

p.s.: the "use a debugger" suggestion from Rambo Ramon and Sam Varshavchik is a good suggestion (IMHO)

p.s.2: sorry for my bad English